# Firebase unsubscribe from topic not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, topic-modeling

I subscribe to a topic in fcm with 2 android devices and after I unsubscribe the topic with one device, I still could send messages with the device that I unsubscribe.

Comment: Did you find any solution/ workaround ?